# SaveFileDialog Filter issues and saved file extension

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have code like this:

```cs
private void Save(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Normal text files(*.txt)|";         
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _viewModel.CurrentSavePath = dlg.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            MainEditor.Save(_viewModel.CurrentSavePath);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

My issues are:

1. I want to add .cs as another option beside .txt:

```cs
dlg.Filter = "Normal text files(*.txt)|C# source file (*.cs)|";
```

doesn't work - incorrent format.

2. Saved file has no extension. I expect it to be .txt or .cs depending what has been chosen.

Comment: Have you though about adding `*.txt` and `*.cs` after the `|` (pipe) separator?

Comment: @Jimi incorrect format.

Comment: Still using the wrong format then: `dlg.Filter = "Normal text files(*.txt)|*.txt|C# source file (*.cs)|*.cs";`

Comment: Ok, now it works. And for some reason it also now saves in proper format, not empty. Thanks for help, never seen this format before.

Comment: That's the standard format. [FileDialog.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter) Property